# Rollback Commit Upon Build/Test Failure on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

Okay, so I've seen a lot of these kinds of questions without really any answers but rather warnings against it. So I understand why it might be annoying/dangerous to do this, and have considered these things. But with how my team project/management is set up (at least for now), it makes a lot of sense for us to just be able to undo a commit on BitBucket when someone commits and Jenkins detects that, pulls, and the build/test fails. Is there any plugin/way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As described in the other answer, it's easier to check before than after.

Actually, there's another idea to try. It basically repeats the manual merging. It would be nice if somebody succeeds in implementing it, and shares their experience.

1. Developers never push to `master` directly. (*)
2. New content is pushed to `master-rc`, which is always a fastforward from `master`. They can be direct pushes from developers of merges from pull-requests, after reviews and some pre-checks. (**)
3. Your CI fetches a specific commit `A` from current `master-rc` and tests if it builds, test passes etc.
4. If all checks are successful, the build artifacts are stored, `master` is fast-forwarded to `A`. Then return to step 3
5. If the check fails, `master-rc` is reset to `master`, and authors of what used to there are informed about failure. Then return to step 3. (***)

This way, you are always sure that master can be built - because it is built already.

(*) except exceptional cases, then the build in progress should be canceled, and `master-rc` is reset to the new `master`, as in case of error. Or, probably if you need this then your `master` is broken, and you should just stop steps 2-6 until it's resolved.

(**) there is a choice - either they do it independently of the build cycle, and there is always possible some new content over `master-rc` - see the next item for this. Or they wait until beginning of the cycle. The latter is more convenient when there are pull-request which can be merged automatically as there is need and it is approved for merging.

(***) if there is more content in `master-rc` than the failed, it can be discarded together with the failed, so that authors can rebase it. Or rebased automatically, but this is already some complication.

Comment: I had same error, but this is a good strategy. because if not exist *-rc jenkins does a loop

Answer (score 1):

Its easy enough to remove the HEAD commit from a branch however, you really cannot safely do this in a jenkins job for a few reasons.

The first reason is that you may not be dealing with a single commit. Depending on how jenkins is configured(ex with a wait perioud) a single jenkins job might encompass multiple commits. Additionally, a user may have pushed multiple commits at once.

Secondly, there is no guarantee that the commit that started Jenkins will still be at HEAD when Jenkins has finished executed. All it takes is someone to push during the time Jenkins is executing and now you would have to attempt a much more complicated rebase that might not be possible without human intervention(Especially since by default you cant rebase a merge commit automatically).

My strong recommendation is instead of trying to remove commits from your master/develop branch consider instead embracing a pattern where something like gitlabs is responsible for merging into master.  You can then set up a multibranch pipeline job in jenkins that auto builds branches and configure gitlabs to prevent merging as long as the jenkins job is failing.  The idea is you create a branch per task and then jenkins merges master into your branch and builds it when you submit a pull request. Only once this build is successful are you allowed to merge into master.

https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/